# How do I return the matched portion of a string in a Pandas Series?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have something like the following code:

`df[df["A"].str.contains("\d+")]`

This effectively matches all rows in a series with the word match somewhere. However, it also matches (as expected), rows of the style:

> 1,"ab: 123"

I would like the function to return **only** the matched portion of the string ("123"), rather than the whole string. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#extracting-substrings) , Example -

```
df[df["A"].str.contains("\d+")]['A'].str.extract("(\d+)")
```

---

Example/Demo -

```
In [41]: df = pd.DataFrame([['123'],['ab 123'],['xyz']],columns = ['A'])

In [42]: df
Out[42]:
        A
0     123
1  ab 123
2     xyz

In [43]: df[df["A"].str.contains("\d+")]
Out[43]:
        A
0     123
1  ab 123

In [47]: df[df["A"].str.contains("\d+")]['A'].str.extract("(\d+)")
Out[47]:
0    123
1    123
Name: A, dtype: object

In [48]: df['A'].str.extract("(\d+)")
Out[48]:
0    123
1    123
2    NaN
Name: A, dtype: object
```